# How to send HTML, CSS and JavaScript together

Tags: rust, actix-web

I try to give the Client the HTML, CSS and JavaScript file but it doesn't work.

```rust
async fn get_homepage() -> impl Responder {
    let html = include_str!("../../../../Frontend/Code/homepage.html");
    HttpResponse::Ok().content_type("text/html").body(html)
}
```

This can only send the HTML and it works fine, but when I try:

```rust
async fn get_homepage() -> impl Responder {
    let html = include_str!("Path of HTML-File");
    HttpResponse::Ok().content_type("text/html").body(html);
    HttpResponse::Ok()
        .content_type("text/css")
        .body("Path of CSS-File")
}
```

I only see the CSS.

How can I display the complete website?

Answer (score 2):

In Rust, the last statement without a semicolon will be treated as the return value so you'll see the first function to return the html file and the second function to return the css file because it is the last statement.

```rust
fn return_two() -> i32 {
    1;
    2
}
```

You need to serve the css and html file on 2 different urls.

```rust
#[get("/")]
async fn ...

#[get("/style.css")]
async fn ...
```

Alternatively, you can inline the css in the html file like this

```html
<head>
<style> /* your style goes here */ </style>
</head>
```

Comment: To clarify: needing separate *documents* (= endpoints) for HTML, CSS, and JS, is a basic web thing. It's possible to *embed* styling and scripting in the HTML but that's usually frowned upon. HTTP2 and HTTP3 also have a notion of *server push* (the server can push ancillary documents), however that's almost entirely unsupported by HTTP3 clients and servers, real-world tests on HTTP2 are mixed, and Chrome is strongly considering dropping server push entirely (if it has not done so already). FF support seems very buggy, and it's unclear that Safari supports it at all.